# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException - Android

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following exception from the following piece of code sometimes
People suggest that if I make the for loop to an iterator, It would fix the issue. But I don't understand If I am not removing any element inside the for loop but calling pendingActions.clear(); later. 
Please let me know if anyone has come across any of this scenario.
Also , Would you think if I make list declaration to

```
private List<Action> pendingActions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

will fix the issue ?

```
 private List<Action> pendingActions = new ArrayList<>();

private void runPendingNavigationActions() {
        if (!pendingActions.isEmpty()) {
            for (Action r : pendingActions) {
                r.run();
            }
            pendingActions.clear();
        }
    }
```

### Exception:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
    at com.app.android.view.fragment.MainFragment.runPendingNavigationActions(MainFragment.java:1355)
```

Comment: Does any `Action` remove itself from the list in its `run()` method?

Comment: No, run doesn't remove from the list but in some race condition  the following code gets executed along while the loop is iterating    /**
     * To ensure actions are done only in between onReusme and onPause, otherwise suspend them to be run once the app is resumed.
     */
    private void runNavAction(Action action) {
        if (!canCommitFragmentTransaction) {
            pendingNavActions.add(action);
        } else {
            action.run();
        }
    }

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If not, pls post the content of `run()` method in your `Action` class here

Comment: Not yet fixed but I don't touch the list inside run method

Comment: @Bulu If that code is running at the same time, that would explain the problem.  Why is that code running in another thread?  And what are these `Action`s?

Comment: @KalaBalik,If I am not removing the items inside the loop what's the point of using iterator approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong data structure: a `Queue` would be a better choice, specifically one designed for concurrent modification.

For example, you can use [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). You can add to this like a list, and then consume the added actions like:

```
Action r;
while ((r = queue.poll()) != null) {
  r.run();
}
```

---

Using `Collections.synchronizedList` would not fix your issue, at least not in and of itself.

The thing to bear in mind about wrapping a list with `Collections.synchronizedList()` is that it only provides mutual exclusion *for each individual method call*, e.g. until the call to `pendingActions.get()` or `pendingActions.iterator()` returns.

The enhanced for loop implicitly creates an `Iterator`; but the list is not then locked while you iterate over it, whether or not this comes from a synchronized list.

Your other thread is changing the list during this iteration, and would still cause the `ConcurrentModificationException` next time you try to get a value from the iterator.

Now, you could make it work (without the CME) by wrapping the iteration in a `synchronized` block *as well*:

```
synchronized (pendingActions) {
  for (Action r : pendingActions) {
    r.run();
  }
  r.clear();
}
```

The problem with this is that other threads will now be blocked whilst the list is being iterated. That might cause a noticeable delay in your app; or it might not, depending upon how frequently this method is called, and how long the actions take to run.

However, using a concurrent queue avoids that issue entirely, and is likely to be faster than a synchronized list too, since non-blocking concurrent queues don't require the use of "full-blown" synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I used  LinkedBlockingQueue and hope should work. I have never been able to replicate the issue but seen in Production Crash logs and hope for the best to test in Prod and shouldn't introduce any new problems with the replacement for LinkedBlockingQueue with ArrayList